# Printer DCP-165c with Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, printing

I have Ubuntu 12.04 version, and a Brother DCP-165c printer. I have used the Brother drivers for this printer.

I can scan documents but I can't print them.

Answer (score 3):

Just installed the DCP 7055 (kubuntu 12.04) and it works a treat. The Brother drivers seem pretty good. Assuming the same procedure:

From here:

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#DCP-165C

Download both the LPR and cupswrapper deb files and install the LPR one first. My experience was that whilst it showed all dependencies satisfied if I installed the cups driver first it produced an error. Then remove the printer and reinstall.

hope that helps